# Channel Images ver 6 upload error

Tags: channel-images, ee3

When I attempt to upload an image using Channel Images v. 6.0 with EE v. 3.0.6 I get the following error:

"The Local Temp dir is either not writable or does not exist"

Both the upload dir and the cache dir are set to 777. I reviewed some old posts and saw that safe_mode might be an issue, but safe_mode isn't even set in the php.ini at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may have done this already, but have you checked your Channel Images setting in the channel field to make sure the correct directory is selected? You can also test the location from there as well.

Comment: Yes, I did this. The directory is correct and it tested out perfectly: /httpdocs/images/uploads/hero_images/
PHP User: 
PHP Safe Mode (OFF): Passed
Is Dir: Passed
Is Readable: Passed
Is Writable: Passed
Create Test File: Passed
Delete Test File: Passed
Create Test DIR: Passed
Rename Test DIR: Passed
Delete Test DIR: Passed